# How to add script to <head>?

Tags: 6, javascript, theming

I want to add a call for 2 external scripts in the page.tpl.php.

The scripts are:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/12345.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

Now in D7 you can call them directly from page.tpl.php like

```
drupal_add_js()
```

right?

But I'm working on a D6 site right now.

So within mytheme directory I add to my template.php file

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    drupal_set_html_head('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/12345.js"></script>');
    $vars['head'] = drupal_get_html_head();
  }
```

It doesn't work. The page no longer loads.

So the question is, How do I get both those scripts in the head? What should the code look like? I know the real answer is learn php, but in the meantime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should concatenate `$vars['head']` no replacing it:
Your code should be:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    drupal_set_html_head('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/12345.js"></script>');
    $vars['head'] .= drupal_get_html_head();
}
```

Notice the `.=` after `$vars['head']`.

Comment: Thanks, that works great for one script. Now how do I add another script? add a whole new function? This doesn't work - http://pastie.org/2183883

Comment: Have you tried to put twice the `drupal_set_html_head` before getting it ? http://pastie.org/2184904

Comment: Another amateur php question - Is it okay that there are two - function service_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
within the template.php file?

Comment: Have you tried ?

Comment: Yeah, it was a no go, but I tried this too and that didn't work either - http://pastie.org/2197838

Comment: Hum strange, I thought this would work... Try this one ;) http://pastie.org/2198067

Comment: Just a note. This does not work in Drupal 7. Call to undefined function drupal_set_html_head()