# How to add Javascript tag in the head tag?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I want to add Javascript in Head Tag. I found an answer in
[How to add script to <head>?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6592) but it doesn't work for a theme.

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  drupal_set_html_head('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/12345.js"></script>');
  $vars['head'] .= drupal_get_html_head();
}
```

Can I add JavaScript code in the `<head>` tag through page.tpl.php?

Comment: Have you read [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722)? And docs of [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the [link](https://drupal.org/node/756722) to the full document on module developing aspect which I assume is not your main goal, there are some ways that you wanna skip for now, my suggestion is depending on the theme you are using, is to do it via `.info` file.   the easiest and common way.

This [link](http://www.webbykat.com/2012/02/adding-custom-javascript-omega-subtheme-drupal-7) is a very good guide for adding js files to omega subtheme, you may find it useful.

### **The .info file approach:**

first open your theme's .info file that it should be something like `YOURTHEMENAME.info`

if you are using a subtheme there must be already some js files in there, you can find them and use them as an example.

what you wanna do is to add your js file like this:

```
scripts[] = somescript.js
```

this way the js file will be added to head of your website, remember after each time of editing a .info file you need to clear cache.

### **Adding External js to your site:**

In your theme's template.php file use [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) to the page preprocess method (or an equivalent preprocess).

```
function hook_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  drupal_add_js('http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js', 'external');
}
```

**Edit**: also with the extra info you just provided regarding **using functions in the header** you need to make a custom tpl file, locate the file that has `<head>` tag in your theme, it most likely be `html.tpl.php` (depends on the base theme you are using) if you couldnt find it you can copy it from `modules/system/html.tpl.php` and paste it into your theme's folder. edit the name of your file as this:
`html--node--id.tpl.php` like `html--node--1.tpl.php` and clear cache afterwards. edit the file as you wish and you must be good to go.

Comment: It appears to me OP needs external js, so the info file is of no use. But maybe that's only my impression based on the question he linked to in his own?

Comment: yea I actually just noticed the link, anyhow I edited the answer and added the external js thing too.

Comment: It is adding path link, as below

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/customjs.js?mvfdgf"></script>

but I want to add script as below in head tag

<script type="text/javascript">
 // some content
</script>

Comment: do you want it to be on a specific page or all of your pages‌?

Comment: I need only for specific page.

Comment: Then first you need to edit your question and add extra information you just provided in this comment and I'll add the details in the answer on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)  function takes an `$options` argument.

This is an array that may have a value for key `scope` as `header` that would place the JS file specified in the header part of your template.

`drupal_add_js('path/to.js', array('scope'=>'header'));`

**Another way if you are working in a module :**

Add this in your module's .info

`scripts[] = somescript.js`

Comment: `drupal_add_js` is deprecated in favor of using the `#attached` key in render arrays.

Comment: really ? I can't see that anywhere on the API documentation... weird, I would still use it as far as D7 is concerned

Comment: I read that link you posted in a comment on the other answer and it only concerns D8 so `drupal_add_js` still looks like a viable solution for @jdln 's issue

Comment: Yes, it will work in D7.  However, there is an active push to try to get people to stop using these functions for new code as it will make the D8 transition harder.  For example, we try to mention whenever we see it during the project application review process.

Answer (score 2):

You can add something like this on your page. Use path and argument to identify the correct page. Or you can add it in hook_init but in that case it will display on all pages which is not recommended.

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });',
    array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'header', 'weight' => 5)
  );
```

Alternatively you can use `drupal_add_html_head` like the following

```
 $inline_script = <<<EOL
      <script src="my_src" type="javascript"></script>
      <script src="my_src" type="javascript"></script></script>
EOL;
    $element = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $inline_script,
    );
    drupal_add_html_head($element, 'jquery-tmpl');
```

Comment: `drupal_add_js` is deprecated in favor of using the `#attached` key in render arrays.

Comment: Finally found your sample how to add custom markup like JSON-LD snippets as in schema.org microdata to the head! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can add javascript to head by using theme_preprocess_html()

```
function theme_preprocess_html(&$var) {
  $script = array(
    '#tag' => 'script',
    '#attributes' => array('type' => 'text/javascript'),
    '#value' => 'Add your javascript here',
   );
   drupal_add_html_head($script, 'script');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing! `drupal_add_js` is your friend here. Documentation for Drupal 7 is here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7

Basically, with `drupal_add_js` you get to select where the JS gets added, from a set of predefined options, which consist of 'header', 'footer', and your regions. So your function call, assuming this is a file in your module/theme, would look something like this:

```
drupal_add_js($path_to_js_file, array('scope' => 'header'));
```

There's a bunch more options you can use, like `type` to define the sort of JS you're adding (inline, external, etc) and `weight` to define the weight of the JS file relative to other JS files. There's more about that on the page linked in the first paragraph.

As for where this goes, I usually put mine in a `hook_init` function if it's part of a module, or in my `hook_preprocess_html` function if it's part of my theme.

There's also the option, if you have an `html.tpl.php` file that you can edit, of directly adding the JS to there. I'm not sure that that's the preferred method, though, and you can't sort where it lands in the list of other JS; it has to either be before the other JS is printed to the page or after it. Overall, not ideal.

Comment: `drupal_add_js` is deprecated in favor of using the `#attached` key in render arrays.

Comment: I thought it was only deprecated in D8?

Comment: It was deprecated for D7 a couple of years ago @Erin (but not removed, for BC reasons)

Comment: @ErinMcLaughlin Yeah, deprecated in D7 and gone in D8, https://www.drupal.org/node/2169605

Comment: Daaang I am behind the times apparently. Can someone post an answer on how you would do this the proper way with a render array from both a module and a theme? I still can't quite wrap my head around render arrays.