# How to add tracking scripts from external sites?

Tags: 7, javascript

We want to use several lead tracking snippets of code on various pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">llfrmid=123456</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://formalyzer.com/formalyze_init.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://formalyzer.com/formalyze_call_secure.js"></script>
```

...I can use drupal_add_js() but it seems to want to wrap the first line in --CDATA-- and I'm unclear if that makes a difference.

I came across this post: [How to add script to <head>?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6592/how-to-add-script-to-head). Is that accepted answer still recommended for D7? ie. just concatenating text to the header with drupal_get_html_head() Or is there a way to use drupal_add_js so it does not wrap the text in --CDATA--?

TIA

Comment: Wrapping in CDATA will not affect the inline script.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the JavaScript on the theme level. You added on `template.php` or any other template that you wish to appear the javascript.

An example is a little bit tricky because is all depend on how the theme is was created. But I can provide an example base on my theme.

I'm using a sub-theme base on Boostrap so on my page.tpl.php I would add the JS on the bottom. So your goal would be to find the footer region and add the JS below that.

```
<?php

?>
<header id="navbar" role="banner" class="<?php print $navbar_classes; ?>">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3">
</div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <?php if ($logo): ?>
      <a class="logo navbar-btn pull-left" href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>">
        <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
      </a>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if (!empty($site_name)): ?>
      <a class="name navbar-brand" href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>"><?php print $site_name; ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <?php if (!empty($primary_nav) || !empty($secondary_nav) || !empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <nav role="navigation">
          <?php if (!empty($primary_nav)): ?>
            <?php print render($primary_nav); ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if (!empty($secondary_nav)): ?>
            <?php print render($secondary_nav); ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if (!empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
            <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </nav>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</header>

<?php if ($page['Featured']): ?>
  <div class="BannerColor">
    <?php print render ($page['Featured']); ?>
  </div> <!-- /. Featured -->
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="main-container container">

  <header role="banner" id="page-header">
    <?php if (!empty($site_slogan)): ?>
      <p class="lead"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
  </header> <!-- /#page-header -->

  <div class="row">

    <?php if (!empty($page['sidebar_first'])): ?>
      <aside class="col-sm-3" role="complementary">
        <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
      </aside>  <!-- /#sidebar-first -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <section<?php print $content_column_class; ?>>
      <?php if (!empty($page['highlighted'])): ?>
        <div class="highlighted jumbotron"><?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?></div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if (!empty($breadcrumb)): print $breadcrumb; endif;?>
      <a id="main-content"></a>
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
        <h1 class="page-header"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php print $messages; ?>
      <?php if (!empty($tabs)): ?>
        <?php print render($tabs); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if (!empty($page['help'])): ?>
        <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if (!empty($action_links)): ?>
        <ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
    </section>

    <?php if (!empty($page['sidebar_second'])): ?>
      <aside class="col-sm-3" role="complementary">
        <?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>
      </aside>  <!-- /#sidebar-second -->
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer container">
  <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
    /**
        Load Custom JS
    **/
  <script type="text/javascript">llfrmid=123456</script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://formalyzer.com/formalyze_init.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://formalyzer.com/formalyze_call_secure.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you please give an answer specific to my example? TIA,

Comment: I have update my answer with an example.